# How to remotely SCP latest file in one server to another?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scp

I have 3 Linux machines, namely `client`, `server1` and `server2`.

I am trying to achieve something like this. I would like to copy the latest file in a particular directory of `server1` to `server2`. I will not be doing this by logging into `server1` directly, but I always log on to `client` machine first. Let me list down the step by step approach which is happening now:

1. Log on to `client` machine using ssh
2. SSH into `server1`
3. Go to directory `/home/user1` in `server1` using the command `ls /home/user1 -Art | tail -n 1`
4. SCP the latest file to `/home/user2` directory of `server2`

This manual operation is happening just fine. I have automated this using a one line script like below:

```
ssh user1@server1 scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /home/user1/test.txt user2@server2:/home/user2
```

But as you can see, I am uploading the file `/home/user1/test.txt`. How can I modify this script to always upload the latest file in the directory `/home/user1`?

Comment: put step 3 and step 4 in a script on server1. execute script via ssh. `ssh user1@server1 "/path/to/script"`

Answer (score 0):

If `zsh` is available on server1, you could use its [advanced globbing features](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to find the most recent file to copy:

```sh
ssh user1@server1 \
  "zsh -c 'scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /home/user1/*(om[1]) user2@server2:/home/user2'"
```

The quoting is important in case your remote shell on server1 is not zsh.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SSH to list the last file and after user scp to copy the file as follow:

```
FILE=$(ssh user1@server1 "ls -tp $REMOTE_DIR |grep -v / | grep -m1 \"\""); scp user1@server1:$FILE user2@server2:/home/user2
```

Before launch these command you need to set the remote directory where to search for the last modified file as:

```
REMOTE_DIR=/home/user1
```